# Chartjs sample can't be reproduced

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2, luxon

I am looking to reproduce the result of this sample from Chartjs doc :
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/time-line.html

What I am looking for is the scale result on x :
[image]

I use react with react-chartjs-2 and a simplified version of the example, but I managed to keep same config and data for the x axis :

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart as ChartJS, registerables } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon';

ChartJS.register(...registerables);

function newDate(days: number) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({ days }).toJSDate();
}

function newDateString(days: number) {
  return DateTime.now().plus({ days }).toISO();
}

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: { display: false },
  },
  scale: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        tooltipFormat: 'DD T',
      },
    },
    y: {
      type: 'linear',
      suggestedMin: 0,
      suggestedMax: 100,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 20,
      },
    },
  },
};

const labels = [newDate(0), newDate(1), newDate(2), newDate(3), newDate(4), newDate(5), newDate(6)];
const Data = [
  {
    x: newDateString(0),
    y: 41,
  },
  {
    x: newDateString(5),
    y: 21,
  },
  {
    x: newDateString(7),
    y: 12,
  },
  {
    x: newDateString(15),
    y: 38,
  },
];

/*...*/
<Line
  options={options}
  data={{
     datasets: [{ data: data }],
       labels: labels,
     }}
/>
```

I got the following result (not even close from sample)
[image]

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your options, the scale configs never get applied since you defined the options for the scales in the `scale` key while they have to be defined in the `scales` key, note the extra s